# Restructure request snippet into class OOP in Python

Tags: python, oop

I've tested this snippet and get the result as expected:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'https://example.com/getlistitem'
headers= {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 
        'Referer': 'http://banggia.tvs.vn/',
        'content-type': 'text/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }

res=requests.get(url, headers = headers, timeout= 30).json()
print(res)
```

Now, I manage to convert it into class as this:

```
class getvps():
    url = 'https://example.com/getlistitem'
    headers= {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0', 
        'Referer': 'http://banggia.tvs.vn/',
        'content-type': 'text/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
    
    def response(self):
        return requests.get(self.url, headers = self.headers, timeout= 30).json()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    print(getvps.response)
```

Unforturnately, the result was: **<function getvps.response at 0x034527C8>**
I have just learned Python and OOP for a few days. Please guide me to learn more via this example. Thanks!

Comment: you didn't call the function - you forgot `()` at the end of it

Comment: Are you sure that `url` and `headers` should be [class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) rather than instance variables?

Comment: Also, it's worth to mention that your current implementation in fact renders using class/OOP useless - everything is hardcoded. The idea is to have a blue-print of an object that can be "basis" for creating multiple instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are blue prints to create objects, so first of all you need to create an instance of getvps class.

```
my_vps = getvps()
```

Then you can call response method on this object, remember for calling a method you should put () at the end of it
so the last line of your code should looks like this:

```
print(my_vps.getvps())
```

By the way it is convention to name classes with capital letters:

```
class Getvps
```

Also there is no need to put () after class name, if your class doesn't inherit from a parent class.
Finally it's better to define url and headers as object attribute rather than class variables